# Leveraging browser caching issue

Tags: htaccess

I am triying to obtain a good calification on Page Speed test, now I've obtained 85 points but I am still on the problem of "Leverage browser caching".

This is the Page Speed test message about this problem:

```
Leverage browser caching
Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.
Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:
https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/…ollowing&lang=es&screen_names=lomasguapa (10 minutes)
http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js (30 minutes)
https://apis.google.com/js/api.js (30 minutes)
https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js (30 minutes)
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js (60 minutes)
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js (60 minutes)
https://oauth.googleusercontent.com/…e:rpc:shindig.random:shindig.sha1.js?c=2 (60 minutes)
http://stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js (2 hours)
http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js (2 hours)
```

However I have seen in many source on Internet that this solution works for this case, the solution is a modification of .htaccess file. There is the first block.

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
**<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>**
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

# REST OF MY .HTACCESS
# BEGIN Better WP Security
Options -Indexes

Order Allow,Deny
Deny from env=DenyAccess
Allow from all
SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^1\.234\.83\.77$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^1\.234\.83\.77$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^1\.234\.83\.77$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^211\.110\.140\.70$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^211\.110\.140\.70$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^211\.110\.140\.70$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^91\.200\.13\.45$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^91\.200\.13\.45$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^91\.200\.13\.45$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^200\.27\.231\.114$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^200\.27\.231\.114$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^200\.27\.231\.114$" DenyAccess
# END Better WP Security

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML (for more page speed)
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>

# remove browser bugs (for more page speed)
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
# END
```

The case is that solution does not work and the page speed is showing again the caching problem. I put all the .htaccess in order to give more information, may be some lines cause any king of problem.

Comment: How is this a wordpress specific problem?

Answer (score 2):

All of the resources listed are third party ones and are externally hosted. You have no control over the caching headers sent by these URLs. You might be able to find advice specific to these scripts if you hunt around a bit, but in all likelihood you won't be able to improve your page speed score for this beyond what you're currently getting.